# Gerenciamento Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Olá.

Trabalho em uma empresa onde para gerenciarmos os projetos temos uma conta no Bitbucket que a tratamos como administrador, e além disso cada um dos colaboradores tem sua própria conta.

Todos os projetos devem estar hospedados na conta do Administrador, e serem compartilhados para os colaboradores.

Quando um colaborador inicia um novo projeto local e sobe esse para o repositório, o mesmo fica hospedado em sua conta pessoal.

Existe alguma maneira de subir esse projeto direto para a conta de Administrador ao invés de deixa-ló na conta do colaborador ?

Obrigado !!

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que adicionar o usuário em Configurações > Geral > Acesso de grupo e usuário.

Ai só clonar o projeto. Tem que ficar atento as chaves ssh de cada um também, caso eles façam clone pelo ssh.

Outra maneira é fazer um fork do projeto e depois fazer um pull request.